# Why this use of apply of dataframe is wrong?

Tags: python, pandas, lambda, apply, series

I don't know why this operation is wrong:

```
songs_genres = np.array(data['genre_ids'].apply(lambda x: int(v) for v in str(x).split('|')))
```

Here's is the log:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "FeatureEngineering.py", line 66, in <module>
    data = FeatureEncoding(data, train_dix, test_idx)
  File "FeatureEngineering.py", line 30, in FeatureEncoding
    songs_genres = np.array(data['genre_ids'].apply(lambda x: int(v) for v in str(x).split('|')))
NameError: global name 'x' is not defined
```

Comment: Can you post how `data['genre_ids']` looks like and what output you want exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's obvious if you use a list comprehension that does something similar:

```
>>> [lambda x: int(x) for _ in range(3)]
[<function __main__.<listcomp>.<lambda>>,
 <function __main__.<listcomp>.<lambda>>,
 <function __main__.<listcomp>.<lambda>>]
```

So what you passed to `apply` are multiple `lambda`s. The amount of `lambda`s depends on `str(x).split('|')`. But that fails because at the time you pass that to `apply` the name `x` isn't defined. That's the reason for the Exception.

You haven't said what you want to do, but something like this seems to be desired:

```
data['genre_ids'].apply(lambda x: [int(v) for v in str(x).split('|')])
```

Which creates a list containing integers for each entry.